# Manually create a JWT token to be used by another API

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, jwt

I have an Asp.NET Web Api v2 setup where I use OAuth (v2) authentication and JSON Web Tokens (JWT). If a user wants access to an endpoint they need to provide the bearer token in the Authorization header. Users need to submit a username and password and if validated they are given an access token (JWT format) that they can then present in the Authorization header. As long as the JWT contains the role accepted by the endpoint all works well.

Now I would like an automated service (another API from another developer) to access one of my endpoints. How do I go about manually generating an access token that has a long expiration date and they can use to access my endpoint without having to submit a username/password. I would like to make it as simple as possible for the outside API to access my API so I just want to be able to hand them a JWT token that they can place in their code.

Comment: What have you tried so far. There are many ways to generate a JWT manually. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @webworm you want to create an isolated token to be used  as credential in your own system. You are in charge of issue and validate. What is really your question?